# javasocketbridge - client not reading / java.net.SocketPermission

Tags: java, websocket

I am trying to achieve a TCP connection between a JavaScript client and a java server. (implementation must be this way I cannot swap to node for the server for example ).

Web sockets implmentation in java looked very complicated. I had a look at Jetty and JWebSocket and was quickly scared off. I have no idea what is going on in the source for them. – So I didn’t have much luck implementing a server using them.

So then I looked for websocket alternatives.

I noticed [SocketBridge](http://stephengware.com/proj/javasocketbridge), It seems very straight forwards and offers exactly what I need for my project so I downloaded that.

I created a simple java server that just prints what I receives and sends a string as bytes back. I used the prebuilt JavaSocketBridge and modified the index.html to point to my server. My server recived the message but nothing showed up on the client.

```
function run(){
        socket_connect('localhost', 31113);
        socket_send("Hello from JavaSocketBridge applet");
    }
```

I then decided to build the JavaSocketBridge to see if I could debug the read methods. However my build of JavaSocketBridge refuses to connect with the error.

```
Java Socket Bridge ERROR: Could not connect to localhost on port 31113 
Access denied (“java.net.SocketPermission” “127.0.0.1:31113” “connect,resolve” )
(This was in chrome but it happens in firefox too)
```

So my questions:

**Why does my build get a socket permission error?**

**Why does the client not receive anything even though the example does from google.com:80?**

Notes.

My [server](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15586644/javaweb/server/Server.java) appears to be working fine. (I have used a simple java [client](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15586644/javaweb/client/Client.java) to test it.
I have used java 1.6 and 1.7 to build the JavaSocketBridge)

I have included C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\plugin.jar
My System is Win7 64 and java SDK / JRE is up to date

**Edit. Ive gone back to jetty and got a client/server working, however I will monitor this question.**